# Tag synonym request: [gksudo] -> [gksu]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

While they [can behave differently](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=5240578#5240578) (mostly on non-Ubuntu systems), `gksu` and `gksudo` are **not really separate topics**. They're provided by the same package (`gksu`). They're even the same executable (which can behave differently depending on how it's invoked...but rarely on Ubuntu). Furthermore, the vast majority of questions asked about them don't have anything to do with any `su` vs. `sudo` distinction.

Therefore, I don't think it makes sense to have separate [gksu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gksu) and [gksudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gksudo) tags. While `gksudo` seems slightly preferred as a command and there are more questions tagged [gksudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gksudo), I think the main tag should be [gksu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gksu) since that is also the package name. But I **don't think it really matters** which is the main tag. I do think we should:

- have both of them (no blacklisting)
- have one of them be a synonym of the other

I would suggest the synonym myself, but I don't have a high enough answer score in the [gksu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gksu) tag. Furthermore, I think the community should decide which should be the main tag.

Comment: I'll vote for the short one. `gksu` as the main tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completed.

Thank you for your attention to detail. :)